# Does mining with multiple computers add up?

Tags: hashpower, mining-theory

Let's say I have four computers, each mining bitcoins at 5 Mhash/s. Is this the same as mining bitcoins on one computer with a speed of 20 Mhash/s?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and that'll net you around 0.01 USD worth of BTC per year (as of January 2016), assuming your power is free.

Comment: Alternately, you can sell your keyboards, and that'll net you more money. You can still use a computer with just a mouse.

Comment: .01 seems generous for 20 Mhash/sec

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the hashrate adds up.

But GPU mining ended in 2013. The tiny bitdust you will earn will never reach a mining pool's minimum cash out limit. So you will never see any bitcoin. This will be a pure loss consisting of spent electricity and worn-out hardware.

You could buy a USB stick for mining, for 10 USD. It would mine at a loss due to electricity costs. Even if you have free electricity it would never earn back the 10 USD. So this would also be a loss.

The only way to mine now is with modern stand-alone miners. They have a much higher hashrate and efficiency and they use a tiny built-in computer instead of connecting to your PC. You'll want to get one that runs 1 TH/s (1000 GH/s) or faster. You will not want to pay more than 0.30 USD per GH/s for a miner with power supply. You will need cheap electricity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. More generally though:

*x* mining machines with an average hashrate of *y* hashes per second will have the same chance of finding an arbitrarily low blockhash in a period of time as one mining machine with a hashrate of *xy* hashes per second in the same length of time.